# Seldom Core Data crashes related to Faulting

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a code block which goes through a number of managed objects and accesses other managed objects from their relations. If works 98% of the time but sometimes it crashes with the following log:

> Thread 6 Crashed:
>
> 0   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x000000018d51af70 objc_msgSend + 16
>
> 1   CoreData                          0x0000000190dddef0 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _retainedObjectWithID:optionalHandler:withInlineStorage:] + 84
>
> 2   CoreData                          0x0000000190e2fc40 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet willReadWithContents:] + 580
>
> 3   CoreData                       0x0000000190dfe1ac -[_NSFaultingMutableSet countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:] + 44

I know the related objects can be Faults. According to the documentation CoreData handles it as following:

> Fault handling is transparent—you do not have to execute a fetch to realize a fault. If at some stage a persistent property of a fault object is accessed, then Core Data automatically retrieves the data for the object and initializes the object.

How can this be explained (given there is no deletion)? Would like to understand it better.

Comment: At a first guess, maybe problems with concurrency. Are you using more than one queue, or calling methods that have callback blocks that might run on different queues?

Comment: Yes. But the queue operating on this data is a serial queue with a child context. Where can be a problem there?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is really late, but I just had this exact same error and hoping this will help others (and myself in the future).  This error is most likely caused by accessing Core Data on a different thread than it started on.  In my case Core Data was being accessed in a completion handler that was no longer on the main thread.

To help with debugging this, you can have your code run with concurrency debugging assertions.  You can enable it by adding `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` in the "Arguments Passed On Launch" section in Xcode's Scheme Editor.  [This article has instructions with that](https://medium.com/@aniket.ghode/solving-coredata-concurrency-issues-3b5a209952e1).  This caused my app to crash consistently whenever core data was accessed from a different thread, making it easy to fix.